# macro to run iterations from data table in existing program

Tags: loops, macros, sas

I am completely unfamiliar with macros/do loops/arrays in SAS, but I have been trying to read up on them. It is not going well.

I have a dataset that has 148,176 rows, 9 columns. I want to run all 148176 combinations one by one through my program (so each row one by one) and have it spit out each result as one long list.  I should have 148176 values at the end.

Before working with the macro piece, I just used macro variables so the user could input each value, like so:

```
%let classIin = 1;
%let classIIin = 0.8;
```

Now I would like to replace each number of the above %let statements with a variable from the 9 columns (each column would correspond to one of the above macro variables, there are 9 I just didn't list them all).

I started trying to write this code, but I am really confused and I know I am missing key things about this process.  If anyone has some helpful video tutorials I should watch, I am happy to do that, because nothing I am finding is helping me much so far.

In the following, "AA" and "AB" are two of the column names in Work.MasterPlanList, but I'm not sure if I can call forth variables in this way.

```
%macro masterlist;
%do i=1 %to 148176;
Data Work.test;
Set work.MasterPlanList(firstobs=&i obs=&i);
call symputx ('classIin', AA)
call symputx ('classIIin', AB)
%end;
%mend;
```

Then I would theoretically call in the %macro in my code, but the other problem is that I need each variable from this list at different times in my code.  Is that an issue or will my macro work by looking at row 1, go through my whole code/calculation set, spit out value 1, then go back to the beginning and look at row 2, go through the code/calc, value 2, etc. etc. etc. until 148176?

Comment: Why would you do something like that? What are going to do with these macro variables?  Are you going to use them to write SAS code?  If so what type of code?

Comment: Explain more about the calculation. Is the role of your data set to store nine parameters used by some target, such as another program or algorithm ?  Are there 148,176 different combinations of parameters for which you will be getting a result ? For certain types of computation you can perform it one row at a time with data step programming statements and not need macro system.  For the case of the parameters being used in a more complex system, such as *result = complex_system(data prep + model step + forecast)* step, the data step can be used to dispatch the complex system.

Comment: Sounds like **Call execute** problem. https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2017/08/02/call-execute-for-sas-data-driven-programming/

Comment: @Richard This is a long program that I already wrote that uses the 9 different variables each at different times throughout the process.  It may well be something about "call execute" as pinegulf mentioned, and I am reading through that blog now.  It readjudicates millions of lines of data, but there are 9 core variables that I want this program to use in 148176 different iterations and then spit out 148176 results.

Comment: Sounds like a long overall process, re-adjudicating millions of rows hundreds of thousands times.  What do you do with the re-adjudicated rows after 1 iteration ? Retain all for next iteration ? Measure the overall affect with a single metric value and store that value in association with the 9 parameters ? I would recommend trying the way described @Tom, but extend your macro to test for a particular combination of parameters already processed and skip over that combination if it is being re-requested by a subsequent rerunning of code.

Comment: I'm going to agree with others. You likely have a too complicated program that doesn't use SAS design model well. Since SAS automatically loops over each and every row in a data set, I'm confused why you'd want a macro to that. If you can show a small base case perhaps we can suggest alternative approaches, but otherwise this sounds like an XY problem. http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to answer without more specifics of the calculations you are doing.  For example you could possibly just do all of your calculations in a data step and never use macro variables or macros.

But if have structured your analysis for one set of parameters as a macro then you can use the dataset to generate multiple calls to the macro.  Although 150K calls to a long complex macro is quite a lot.

Say you had a macro called %MYMACRO that had 2 input parameters. And you had a SAS dataset with 2 variables with the values for those parameters.  You could then use CALL EXECUTE() or other code generation methods to generate one macro call per observation.

For code generation on this scale I find that using a data step to write the code is easier to understand and debug than using CALL EXECUTE.  Especially if you name your dataset variable with the same names as the macro parameters.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set my_metadata ;
  file code ;
  put '%mymacro(' var1= ',' var2= ')';
run;
%include code /source2;
```